# Graphic Visualizer with DirectX SampleGrabber in C#

Tags: c#, directx, directshow

Thanks for reading, I have the following code to read m4a audio files and I am kind of lost as to what the next step is. I know that I need to implement SampleGrabber to grab the samples. Ideally I would like to be able to get the peaks and the current audio frequencies, much like the simple itunes visualizer does if you click the arrow at the top of the screen. Right now though, I'm mainly worried about adding the sampleGrabber to my graph, and getting SampleCB called. Here is my graph construction:

```
public class Player
{
    private IGraphBuilder graphbuilder;
    private IMediaControl imc;
    private IMediaEventEx imex;
    private IMediaPosition imp;
    private IBasicAudio iba;
    private ISampleGrabber isg;

    public Player(string file)
    {
        graphbuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
        graphbuilder.RenderFile(location, null);

        imc = (IMediaControl)graphbuilder;
        imex = (IMediaEventEx)graphbuilder;
        imp = (IMediaPosition)graphbuilder;
        iba = (IBasicAudio)graphbuilder;
    }
}
```

I have other methods in the class for playback, volume, ect.. and have extended all of the properties to make them animatable, WPF-style, hehe. Now I just don't know where to add SampleGrabber in the GraphBuilder, and how to make it go to a SampleCB method. Also, do I have to make the entire class inherit from ISampleGrabberCB? I have tried these different combinations, but couldn't make anything work...

Comment: I'm not sure you will be able to do this with a call to RenderFile which builds the graph automatically. I believe that you will have to manually add the filters to your graph. To add your source file you can use the AddSourceFilter method on the GraphBuilder and specify the filename. You will need to create a sampleGrabber with something like  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGrabberF));, connect your pins and set your callback. Unfortunately I don't think you can use the automatic graph creation if you need to add a sampleGrabber.